# Xamarin. X509Certificate and ClientBase

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, x509certificate2

I'm working on xamarin app which working with web service.

Does Xamarin support X509Certificate in System.ServiceModel.ClientBase?

Next code working in project builded with .Net 4.5:

```
public void Initialize()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://ThereIsMyServerAddress/PathToService");

        _mobileService = new ServiceClient(binding, endpoint);

        _mobileService.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("Ivanov_Ivan_Ivanovich.cer");

    }
```

But Xamarin doesn't see ClientCertificate.Certificate in ClientCredentials.

Is there any solution to add certificate to ServiceClient?

Comment: Is it important to use certificate? You can just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be done as a dependency, not through the PCL, please see [https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/271718#Comment_271718](http://It%20has%20to%20be%20done%20as%20a%20dependency,%20not%20through%20the%20PCL,%20please%20see%20https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/271718#Comment_271718)